# Siebel - Issue of a missing account

Tags: siebel

An account seems to be missing in accounts screen. On querying the DB i found that all the previous year records that were associated are being displayed instead of the current years records.

On analysing,I found this RUle Set in the Personalization Screen. The below mentioned expression was provided in the "Included Expression" field of the Rule Set.

[LN Position Year] = [LN Calc Current Year] OR [LN Position Year] IS NULL OR [LN Position Year] = ""

This should have filtered and displayed the current year accounts. But this expression seems to be overridden.

I tried using that expression in that expression in the Applet Search Spec of the SIS Account Entry Applet.It didnt seem to have any effect.

How do i proceed with this issue?

Comment: You're not providing enough information to anybody willing to help you. At least, you should mention which Siebel version are you using, especially given that you suspect your problem to be caused by an upgrade... Which version did you upgrade from? To which one? --- Also, what restrictions were made, in which business component? What restrictions set in Admin - Personalization are being overriden? Where do you query "a set of records"?

Comment: Kindly let me know if u require more info?

Comment: Uh, such as the more information he already asked you for?

Comment: I dont get u - tripleee